# Retrofit 2.0 Android Unit Testing using Local JSON

Tags: android, json, unit-testing, retrofit

I'm new to Retrofit 2.0 and I want to ask about the best way to do unit test using this, especially for asynchronous request.

I found a good article about it [here](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2014/02/24/integration-testing-rest-apis-for-android.html) and I'm interested on using the local JSON static files for my unit testing since it will be faster in my opinion and doesn't always require internet connection, but it won't work when I implement it on Retrofit 2.0. Is it possible to do this in Retrofit 2.0?

Or maybe can somebody here help me with good references or maybe some good examples about how to do these unit tests?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick translation of the referenced approach for retrofit 2 implemented using an OkHttp [`Interceptor`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).  I gave it a quick test, but nothing too deep.  Let me know if you have issues with it.

```
public class LocalResponseInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private Context context;

    private String scenario = null;

    public LocalResponseInterceptor(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public void setScenario(String scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        URL requestedUrl = request.url();
        String requestedMethod = request.method();

        String prefix = "";
        if (this.scenario != null) {
            prefix = scenario + "_";
        }

        String fileName = (prefix + requestedMethod + requestedUrl.getPath()).replace("/", "_");
        fileName = fileName.toLowerCase();

        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw",
                context.getPackageName());

        if (resourceId == 0) {
            Log.wtf("YourTag", "Could not find res/raw/" + fileName + ".json");
            throw new IOException("Could not find res/raw/" + fileName + ".json");
        }

        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);

        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(inputStream);
        if (mimeType == null) {
            mimeType = "application/json";
        }

        Buffer input = new Buffer().readFrom(inputStream);

        return new Response.Builder()
                .request(request)
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .code(200)
                .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), input.size(), input))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Add this interceptor to a custom `OkHttpClient` --

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new LocalResponseInterceptor(context));
```

where `context` is an android `Context`.

and add that client to your Retrofit --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

Comment: Can I see how you use this in the unit test? I tried to use this using Robolectric and I got this error `Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Michael did you figure this out? I know it's from long ago..